# Android - Google Map shows blurry screen when map move

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a fragment map view:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/llHeader" />
```

And map move to current location when receive GPS signal and Google Map shows blurry screen.
Any body help me, sorry for my English.

[image]

Comment: What zoom you set when paint the point in map? Maybe its the reason

Comment: @brayan camilo villate leon: I dont set zoom when animate Map.   
mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlng));

Comment: Try this. mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latlng), 12));

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`mMap.animateCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom( new LatLng( latlng ), 12 ) );`